# Checking live console output from Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I am using Bamboo to set a up CI for out project.
Is there anyway to check live console output from Bamboo tasks that are currently executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Click on the Dashboard link, it will take you to a screen showing running jobs. Clicking on these jobs will get you to the live console output.